# How to view NSLog of a native module in Xcode9?

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode9, react-native-ios

I have a native module that I wrote in objective C, as a library for my react naive ios app, that exposes two functions.

However, while debugging, I can't see the NSLogs in the xcode console nor in the console from the simulator.

Even when I give NSLog inside the appDelegate.m file, I don't see them in the console when the app is running.

I tried using printf as well but it does not work.

Comment: `NSLog` in native iOS code will be visible only in xCode bottom `output` console

Comment: I know that but the logs that I give won't appear in the Xcode console

Comment: Did you add ```OS_ACTIVITY_MODE```   ?

Comment: I get all the react native logs that are auto generated, except the NSLogs that I give